# How to insert item at index in a DynamoDB list using update_item and Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a simple DynamoDB table structure:

```
{
 id: '123_456',
 number_list: ['a', 'c']
}
```

And I would like to add `'b'` in the middle (or at some specific index) of this array.

What I know is that we can use `list_append()`to add it at the end such as:

```
table.update_item(
 Key={'id': '123_456'},
 UpdateExpression="SET number_list = list_append(number_list, :nl)"
 ExpressionAttributeValues={ ':nl': ['b'] }
)
```

This will result in `['a', 'c', 'b']` but I want `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Is there a way to achieve this or should I get the stored list, add at index in python and store it again with:

```
SET list_number = :nln
{ ':nln': ['a', 'b', 'c'] }
```

I know we can delete at index with `REMOVE list_number[1]` which will result in `['a']`. I would like to find something similar.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct new list from older one - if you know exactly where change should happen. [Here](https://aws-blog.de/2021/04/working-with-lists-in-dynamodb.html) is an example - search for "Appending to a list and updating a specific value at the same time". From that I would try with:

```
UpdateExpression=f"SET #nl[1] = :repl",
ExpressionAttributeNames={
    "#nl": "number_list",
},
ExpressionAttributeValues={
    ":repl": "b"
},
```

### UPDATE (after comment)

Code above will change "c" to "b". So `["a","b"]`, not `["a","b","c"]`. My personal solution would be making whole list, and updating it. On the other hand update expression can have more operations like:

```
UpdateExpression=f"SET #nl[2]=#nl[1], #nl[1]=:repl",
```

Perhaps someone would do that if there are many elements - not 3. In that case - shifting all of them by one... is questionable. In that case I would use `list_append`:

```
UpdateExpression=f"SET #nl = list_append(#nl[0], #nl), #nl[1]=:repl",
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will replace number_list[1] by b and we will have ```['a', 'b']```?